# Why do I receive a Exception has occurred: StaleElementReferenceException error with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to using Selenium and trying to pull the names of the potential presidential candidates, the url to their profiles, an image link of them, and their party. I'm navigating to the initial page, and then want to go to their respective profile pages to pull the image and their party. I am receiving an "Exception has occurred: StaleElementReferenceException" error, which I think has something to do with navigating to the profile URL, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Appreciate any help.

Code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
pres_candidates_url = "https://ballotpedia.org/Presidential_candidates,_2024"
driver.get(pres_candidates_url)

def parse_profile(profile_url): #this will return the official_image, metadata(only includes party for now)
    driver.get(profile_url) #opens candidate profile page
    party = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='widget-row value-only white']//a").text
    try:
        official_image = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='widget-row']//img").get_attribute("src")
    except:
        official_image = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mw-parser-output']//p//img").get_attribute("src")
    metadata = {"Party:": party}
    print(official_image, metadata)
    return [official_image, metadata]

elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mw-parser-output']//ul//li//b//a")

all_members = []
for elem in elems:
    member = {}
    words = elem.text.split()

    count = 0
    for word in words: #remove non-candidate names if more than one word is lowercase
        if word[0].islower(): 
            count +=1 
    if count < 1:
        name = elem.text
        member_url = elem.get_attribute("href")
        print(name, member_url)
        official_image, metadata = parse_profile(member_url)
        print(name, member_url, official_image, metadata)
        member["name"], member["url"], member["official_image"], member["metadata"], = name, member_url, official_image, metadata
    else:
        continue
    all_members.append(member)

print(all_members)
```

From the https://ballotpedia.org/Presidential_candidates,_2024 I'm expecting to get their name and the url to their profile page and from each respective candidate's profile page I'm expecting to retrieve the candidate image link and their party.

Answer (score 0):

- You can do this using exception handling. You are mostly likely getting this error because you are not waiting for the element.

Sample from your Code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
pres_candidates_url = "https://ballotpedia.org/Presidential_candidates,_2024"

try:
    driver.get(pres_candidates_url)
    party = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='widget-row value-only white']//a")))
    party = party.text
    metadata = {"Party:": party}
     # rest of the code 

except StaleElementReferenceException:
    print("An error occured")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. Does it have something to do with the fact that I navigate to a new driver window, and thus when I go back through the for loop in elem in elems, the DOM no longer exists?

Comment: @Noey I can see that in the "parse_profile" function, you are calling the driver again, when it was already initialized outside the function. Can you comment that out? Also use try/except clause when you are calling it inside the function.  Most likely the page is not fully loaded since you are not waiting after you initialize the driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stale element references occur when the page is loaded, when the elements are shuffled, and the Selenium APIs are unable to locate them.

The below mechanism might work for you.

Webdriverwait waits=new webDriverWait();
waits.until(ExpectedCondition.invisibleoflocator(driver.find(By.xpath("")));
```